# Book where a boy learns to use science as a form of magic

Tags: story-identification, books

A boy and his mother move to a town, where a teacher has learned to control the elements and change their surrounding. A secret organization learns of this and removes the children but not the teacher. Their families don't remember them. The boy uses a stone to channel his powers. Later he goes through a series of challenges where he learns that he has the most power out of all of them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Physical or e-book?  Do you recall the cover at all?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.